# Restangular using app context inconsistently

Tags: angularjs, restangular

I have an issue with Restangular using my sites context inconsistently. I have a site running at `example.com/app-name`. When making the below call I am expecting it to hit `example.com/app-name/foo`

```
angular.module('myApp').factory('File', File);
File.$inject = [ 'Restangular' ];
function File(Restangular) {
    var service = {
        postFiles : postFiles
    };
    return service;

    function postFiles(files) {
        return Restangular.all('foo').post(files);
    }
}
```

However, it hits `example.com/foo` instead.

While not ideal, I figured I would set the base url for now to work through this issue and then just create a build step to handle the different environment app names.

```
angular.module('myApp').run(run);
run.$inject = [ 'Restangular' ];
function run(Restangular) {
    Restangular.setBaseUrl('app-name');
}
```

After this though, it now hits `example.com/app-name/app-name/foo`.

My current solution to the problem is to do

```
Restangular.one('app-name').all('foo').post(files)
```

Which works but, again, will require some build tasks setup to make configurable which is less than ideal.

I've also tried setting the `<base>` tag to the following:

```
<base href="/app-name/" />
```

And the requests still go to `example.com/foo` instead of `example.com/app-name/foo`.

Is there something I'm missing in the setup or use of Restangular? Why is the app context being used differently in these two scenarios?

Comment: What happens if you move `Restangular.setBaseUrl('app-name')` into your module's `config` function?

Comment: It's the same in either.

Comment: Can you provide a codepen or something? From the code you provided, everything should work so I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: @kuhnroyal I don't believe codepen or anything can replicate an application context, which is why I haven't provided one. Unless there is something I am mistaken about. Otherwise, what makes you think the setup I have should work? Do you have a working example of what I'm describing? I have other projects working but this one is setup slightly different and it seems to make all of the difference in how restangular works.

Comment: Probably true, hard to replicate there. In all my apps with custom context-path I only set the `<base href="app-name/">` tag and Restangular takes care of the rest.

Comment: @kuhnroyal that's something I haven't heard of trying before. But it also runs me into the same issue that I would need to change that per environment. It looks like it would be cleaner to do in the html than in the js though.

Comment: Changing it in HTML is defenitely the way to go since it also takes effect on links etc. How to do that depends on your platform though.